# AccessibilityService: How make a scroll action "step by step"?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm using **ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD** of [`AccessibilityNodeInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo) but this action "eat" part of content that still not was saw .

Then i want know if exists a possibility of make a action of scroll not only FORWARD, that can be more slow and not "eat" part of content that still not was saw.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at `ACTION_SCROLL_TO_POSITION` instead? May ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN would help as well. There are a lot of different actions, available for this. `ACTION_SCROLL_UP`/`ACTION_SCROLL_DOWN` is also worth looking at.

Comment: Thank you by answer, but i think that this not will scroll to up or down like i wish, in others words i think that [`ACTION_SCROLL_TO_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction?hl=ar#ACTION_SCROLL_TO_POSITION) not is the solution to scroll slowly ("step by step") to up or down.